# Cups can't find file to send to Printer

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I am running on Ubuntu 19.10 and I am trying to print a file with an Epson-ET4750 via WIFI.

When I print a test-page: all goes well.

When I try to print anything else: I see the job being sent and I see it completed, but nothing is printed.

In the cups error-log I see the following:

> [Job 49] File \'\' not found

It seems to me, that cups does not know what file I am trying to send. How can this be caused? And what to do about it.

Comment: I am also running Ubuntu 19.10 and see a similar problem with a HP ENVY Photo 6230. Many times the printer just displays "cancelling". Even when it works, the error message appears, so perhaps it is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try to manually add the printer with connection (DeviceURI) socket or ipp. In my case it works.

Comment: If this were stated as: "Manually add the printer with connection (DeviceURI) socket or ipp", it might very well answer the question.  Thomas indicates that this is the solution for his system.